# Can we freeze amount of token, amount of time with smart contract code?

Tags: solidity, tokens, block-interval

Is there a smart contract code to freeze amount of token amount of time. For example i have 20 ether, with a smart contract code can i freeze it 1 year, even i can not touch it? With that code our ether will freeze in our account or blocked somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an escrow contract that hold your Eth for you and only allows the original sender of the Ether withdraw after a certain amount of time.